# Как преобразовать минимизированный код в удобочитаемый?

Tags: php

[image: код]

Подскажите, пожалуйста есть ли какие онлайн генераторы или плагины, что б привести его к читабельному виду

Comment: скорее всего там поработал шифровальщик. А такой код не восстановить

Comment: А там разве не просто подмена знаков на utf символы ?

Comment: Не похоже на него по первому взгляду. как минимум вставьте его сюда https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode или любой другой `utf decode online` Проверьте. Но это не он

Answer (score -1):

в программах от IDEA есть горячая клавиша CTL+ALT+L которая восстановит порядок.